# 2010: Update Title column values on condition

Tags: 2010, custom-list, calculated-column

I need the Title column (the one which is linked to item) of a custom list to take a default value 'a' if column X is empty and 'b' if X is not empty. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You need to do using CSOM or server side code or sharepoint designer ? OOTB way is not possible.

Comment: I would prefer CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, but 3 of them are:

1. Create a small workflow to check the column X. If it is empty, then set Title in current item to 'a' else set Title in current item to 'b'
2. Check the column x value with jQuery, by adding PreSaveAction function and check the values

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function PreSaveAction() 
       {
           var title = $("input[title='Title']");
           var column_x = $("input[title='column_x']").val();
           if(column_x == '') title.val('a');
           else title.val('b');
       }
   </script>
   ```
3. Attach an event receiver to your list on item created. To create event receiver on specific list, please refer to this article:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx